# How should I Implement TBMP Rematch?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-notifications, google-play-games

I'm creating a multiplayer tic tac toe game and it works for the most part, but when it's time to rematch I'm getting less than desirable functionality.

So originally I used the same implementation of `Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.rematch` as the TBMPSkeleton sample project. Basically after calling `Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finish`, I check whether or not the match can be rematched by calling `match.canRematch()` during the subsequent callback. If `match.canRematch()` returns true, then I call `Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.rematch`. Both, when I call finish and when I call rematch, the `onTurnBasedMatchReceived` callback gets called on the opposing client device and from there I check the match object for the rematchId. If it's not `null`, then I reset the game.

The problem I'm having is that, after the winning player has requested a rematch and then takes his/her turn, the opposing player receives an invite to the new match, but the `onTurnBasedMatchReceived` callback doesn't get called. I don't want the losing player to have to leave my game in order to accept or dismiss the invitation.

So is there a way to have my app handle the invitation notification without forcing the player to have to open the system's notification gui? Should I scrap the turn based multiplayer API in favor of it's real-time counterpart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I didn't have a listener registered for invitations. After registering one, I was able to achieve my desired functionality. I'm relieved that it's working, but it would have been nice to notice that much sooner...